# Unable to create data driven subscription for ssrs report

Tags: t-sql, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have a SSRS report which displays daily status report for the team members. The dataset of the report depends on User!UserID as a parameter which is passed to the SQL Query to fetch the data. I want to create a data driven subscription on this report so that every user gets his/her daily status report each morning. But when I click on the "New Data-Driven Subscription" I get a message "Data-driven subscriptions cannot be created because the credentials used to run the report are not stored, the report is using user-defined parameter values, or if a linked report, the link is no longer valid."

One of the solutions to the above issue is provided at  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlreportingservices/thread/94ad2583-4591-4d28-add3-629b9565c27d. The post says "Make sure your report does not contain expressions depending on user like User!UserID".

If I remove User!UserID from the expression how can I fetch the data on individual user basis. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work around is provided here http://www.fits-consulting.de/blog/PermaLink,guid,12db87cf-9d2f-4a2f-9f1b-a6cc1f692ea7.aspx.

Many thanks to Markus Fischer.

Comment: Link is broken. do you have a local copy?

Comment: using google cache :
[link](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:OPT1WgGgBGEJ:social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/cb4e7816-d421-4921-a4e5-b258888748f9/+&cd=1&hl=fr&ct=clnk&gl=fr)

Comment: Google cache link is broken too.